# Google Application Licensing is not responding

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement the Application Licensing Check for my paid app.

I gone through the application licensing guide [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/) and implemented all the things as described in it.

1) Downloaded and implemented the LVL from [here](https://github.com/google/play-licensing)

2) Got the PUBLIC_KEY from Play Console and added to my code

3) Launched the app to close testing

But still i am not getting any response when I check for the license status.

I also don't get any error --- and --- no response also

Answer (score 0):

This issue has also bothered me all day. It's due to a bug in google play version 10.7.17 and 10.7.18. Reference links:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110978499

or

https://www.xda-developers.com/latest-play-store-breaks-license-verification-paid-apps/